# How can I update the title of the tab in the same way GMail/Facebook does?

Tags: javascript

Every time you receive a new email, or something happens on your Facebook profile, your browser tab's name changes. For example, on gmail, if you receive a new mail, it will change to something like `GMail (1)`. How can I get the same effect in my application? I think it's a Javascript thing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 12.5k rep? :P no offence! but this is kind of basic.

Comment: @Achshar - Someone could have 100K and still be a beginner at something.

Comment: alright so you are native all the way.. or python.. no worries :)

Comment: @ash yes yes, i totally understand that, as i said i meant no offence. I just thought maybe he got confused, but js is not his forte and that's perfectly ok. Everyone has to start sometime, right?

Comment: @Achshar, I'm not a Web developer. I was thinking the `document.title` was the way to go, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: well its good you know now :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be as simple as modifying the `document.title` property with JavaScript:

```
document.title = "New title (1) new message";
```

Answer (score 3):

can be done using jQuery (Javascript library)

This sample will change title of page 2 seconds after document fully loads

```
function changeTitle(new_value){
    $("title").val(new_value);  //this line changes value of <title> element
    //pure javascript:  document.title = new_value;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout('changeTitle("New Title")',2000); //calls function changeTitle() after 2secs
});
```

Comment: I don't see a `jQuery` tag on this question.

Comment: it is javascript, he doesn't know properly in which tag should this be placed if he don't know the answer. Correct me please if I'm wrong

Comment: Also, there is no need to over complicate an already simple task.

Comment: @Ash: he is asking how to do it in way the facebook (etc) does it. So I showed him how to wrap it into function and how to delay change of title, if I can't show him background ajax task to grab data to place them into title. so why do you complain?