# Facebook (1) - Update Browser Title With New Notification Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I update the title of the tab in the same way GMail/Facebook does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456010/how-can-i-update-the-title-of-the-tab-in-the-same-way-gmail-facebook-does)

How is it possible to update my browser title value, like Facebook and Yahoo, to show a number that represents notifications/pending items/new messages etc.

Right now, my Facebook page title/tab reads [ (3) Facebook ], which indicates I have 3 unread notifications.

How is this possible? I reckon it uses JS and AJAX but I maybe wrong. Has anybody got any snippets, links or suggestions that will get me started in this?

It's a really nice feature but don't seem to find many websites using it, neither can I find any decent tutorials or examples.

Many thanks

Comment: I did use the search before writing the question thank-you very much. However, I could have altered my search to find the right results, I admit.

Comment: Searching for: "ajax update browser title" didn't find much at all. Please ask me if I used the search, before telling me to use the search

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a property of the document object

```
document.title = "some string";
```

Use whatever logic you like to determine what information you want to put in there.

Be aware that it will produce some really odd bookmark names.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change title of your page using javascript.

if you are using jquery, it is as simple as -

```
 $('title').text('someText (3)')
```