# How to change tab colour with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I alert the browser content has changed with JQuery / javascript like Facebook, Twitter do where the tab colour changes?

Comment: I have never seen FB changing the tab color (if we talk about browser tabs) and I doubt that's possible.

Comment: Is this a real question? which tab? Certainly not the built in tabs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I update the title of the tab in the same way GMail/Facebook does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456010/how-can-i-update-the-title-of-the-tab-in-the-same-way-gmail-facebook-does)

Comment: The m.facebook.com page changes the chrome with blue colored address bar instead of general white color theme. Yes, it is a color/theme change definitely. But again, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do this automatically when the title of the tab changes. You can set the title using the `document.title` property.

Comment: ahh the OP means flashing the tab